# How to get authentificated user from database in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

i want do display the Emailadress of the current logged in user. But i don't know, how to get it. I searched many hours and i found nothing. I found some snippet to get the name, but no snippet to get the other fields like email or phonenumber. 
The user in this snippet don't have a Id to get it from database.

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Write user info to console</button>
<br />
<br />
@Message

@code {
    string Message = "";

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Message = ($"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.");
        }
        else
        {
            Message = ("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core Blazor with Identity, the Claims will not contains email claim.

For getting user, you could try `UserManager.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)` like below:

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager;

<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Write user info to console</button>
<br />
<br />
@Message

@code {
    string Message = "";

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);
            Message = ($"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated. Email is { currentUser.Email }");
        }
        else
        {
            Message = ("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. is this complicated. I need the user-id at every change and adding func on Database. Now i must insert on every component 3 lines of code? is there a way to recycle the code like a service class or derivation of the class?

Comment: MSDN: SignInManager<TUser> and UserManager<TUser> aren't supported in Razor components (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're not passing the email address as part of the claim back from the authentication mechanism. Not sure which provider you're using (Identity Server, etc), having a look at the following link, specifically the section that talks about Claims and Procedural Logic might be the answer to your question: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Again, I believe the issue is with the Claim. Once you have the email coming through in the claim, you should, in theory have access to it via the common principal in code.